# What is the maximum supported image size for a Facebook page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

What is the maximum supported image/pixel dimensions size for a facebook page (without requiring resizing)?

Does this size change often or is there some other reason it would be unwise to utilise the full image size allocation?

Comment: Are you talking about the canvas or the profile picture ?

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is 180 width x 540 height for profile pictures.

Though the [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/) says otherwise

> The URL to the largest-sized profile
>   picture for the user being queried.
>   The image can have a maximum width of
>   200px and a maximum height of 600px.
>   This URL may be blank.

It could be this change is still being propagated.